# Jira Rest API and python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to get all the issues which are in rejected/implemented state with the reporter name/email id.

Below is my code.

How to get it from JSON?

```
import random
import sys
import os
import jira.client
import json
import logging
import datetime
import base64
import requests
import urllib
from jira.client import JIRA
serverURL='http://ontrack-internal.amd.com'
query='project = SWDEV AND issuetype = Defect AND status in (Implemented, Rejected) AND "Deliverable ID" = "17.50 Sustaining [969960]" AND "Target SW Release" = "17.50 [694916]" AND status in (Implemented,Rejected) ORDER BY updated DESC'
jql='/rest/api/2/search?jql=%s' % urllib.parse.quote(query)
response=requests.get(serverURL+jql,verify=False,auth=("userid","pass"))
print (response.json())
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error?

Comment: no error just i need to get the reporter email id from json file and the tickets sorted

Comment: can you provide the output of the print statement please

Comment: it's just a json file like jira query issues which has implemented and rejected tickets

Comment: Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: It is still not clear what the problem is. Is there something wrong with the JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

```
response=requests.request("GET", serverURL+jql, verify=False, auth=("userid","pass"))
issue_content = json.loads(response.text)
reporter = issue_content["fields"]["reporter"]
print(reporter["name"])
print(reporter["emailAddress"])
```